# Spring Webflux body runs twice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am trying the below code in Spring WebFlux but it runs 2 times. I am using Spring Boot 2.3.3.RELEASE and MongoDB as database.

There are 3 repositories called: sessionRepo, userRepo, requestRepo

```
public Mono<CustomeResponse> createUpdateUser(Request request) {
  return sessionRepo
    .findBySid(request.getId())
    .log()
    .flatMap(sessionInfo -> userRepo.findById(sessionInfo.getUid())
            .log()
            .map(quoteDocument -> {
    // other update user logic
                userRepo.save(user).subscribe();
    return success;
            })
            .onErrorReturn().defaultIfEmpty())
    .switchIfEmpty(createNewUser(request))
    .onErrorReturn());
    }


public Mono<Success> createNewUser(Request request){
   return requestRepo.findById(request.getRequestInfo().getId())
     .log()
     .map(requestInfo -> {
        // other create user logic
        userRepo.save(user).subscribe();
        return success;
      })
      .defaultIfEmpty()
      .onErrorReturn();
}
```

I have noticed most of my code runs 2 times. But all the API’s where I must create new ID’s like session-id and send it to the Front end it always sends the second one creating a duplicate in the database.

Even switchIfEmpty runs 2 times.

Comment: `flatMap` loop items one by one in your case `sessionRepo.findBySid(request.getId())` have multiple items that's why your switchIfEmpty runs twice can you confirm from your end ?

Comment: `userRepo.save(user).subscribe()` is also not good you should not be subscribing. The subscriber is the consumer, so in your case its the calling client (webpage, mobile app) since they are the ones that initiated the call, and its the final destination of the response, instead you should `return userRepo.save(user).thenReturn(success)`

Comment: Hi @Toerktumlare, you are right one of the issues is .subscribe(). I have added the sample code to my git repo: https://github.com/prathambongale/reactive-practice. The README file has the info on what problem I am trying to solve.